# Microservices Design for different type of Entities

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, microservices, domain-driven-design

I just want to get a high-level idea of how to design/write microservices for the following use case:

client Microservice MediaStore (let's call it A) talks to two other different microservices

1. Microservice Movie (B)
2. Microservice Book (C)

A User may want to view/order a Movie or Book from the MediaStore.
I understand that Movie microservice will have its Movie entity and MovieDB and similarly, Book microservice will have its Book entity and BookDB. Since the user can order, there is an 'Order' entity on the MediaStore microservice side.

But how to design/write/use them on the client MediaStore Microservice?

a) Should I be using another generic entity (let's say Item) as a parent interface for movies and books, so that I can interact with a generic entity (Item)?
The reason being, I want to create an entity 'Order' in the MediaStore microservice. Order can be of Movie or Book.

b) Or should I be using them separately only as Movie and Book entities? And thus create MovieOrder and BookOrder as orders in MediaStore microservice.

**c) It would be really helpful if I could get any other advice/knowledge/tip on this use case from the StackOverflow community. :)**

Answer (score 0):

If there are different attributes between these entities (movies and books), and I suppose so, microservice A has to manage two different entities so you should pick the B option.

With this approach, your order entity will include a list of items and an Item must store the item type so you can convert it to the original entity in order to get its specific information

Answer (score 0):

A major part of DDD is recognizing when definitions change (those changes delineate bounded contexts).  It's generally a good idea to have your micro-/macro-services (macroservices being for this purpose a single service that happens to deploy as cooperating microservices) stay within one bounded context.

So with that in mind, you may want to think about the purpose of the MediaStore.  If its purpose is just to manage orders, is there really a difference between books and movies?  If there isn't, then in the context of the MediaStore, all you need is "item" and that can have a property saying "is this a book or a movie".  It won't have anything specific to books or movies: things like author, stars, director, etc. would be properties of the book and movie entities, which would have a property (or maybe even zero or one, or one or more, or zero or more: think about how you might deal with books or movies that aren't for sale/preorder, or that have many distinct editions...) linking them to items.  You'd then have book/movie services to manage the book/movie-specific information.